# How to get the full word to use abbreviation in any time in java

Tags: java, abbreviation

Hi i was using autohotkey for get a full word to type abbreviation like as

typing s8f, it is to be "select * from" at anytime when i wanted.

it calls hotstring in autohotkey but i couldn't get it or hint to use in java.

is there any methods or library whatever i could get a hint to do like this work?

thank you
Jason.

Comment: How are you trying to use this in Java .. In an IDE?

Comment: hi @J_D  i'm working in eclipse photon with java version 8

Comment: Please clarify...Are you looking for the auto complete feature in eclipse or are you looking for spelling suggestions?

Comment: hi @J_D i'd want to use it to any windows or application i mean notepad or SqlLight whatever.